# Iterating over symmetric sparse matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am following the following example to loop through the elements of a sparse matrix.

```
SparseMatrix<double> mat(rows,cols);
for (int k=0; k<mat.outerSize(); ++k)
  for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(mat,k); it; ++it)
  {
    it.value();
    it.row();   // row index
    it.col();   // col index (here it is equal to k)
    it.index(); // inner index, here it is equal to it.row()
  }
```

I am completely fine with this example. However, the matrix I have is symmetric and I only want to iterator through the lower part. Is there any easy way to iterate through a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Why can't you iterate the inner loop until `it.row() > k` (or it reaches the end)?

Comment: @MFisherKDX yes, I think it is an easy way to do it. But the only minor issue is that the inner loop will still go through the upper half of the column until it.row() > k

Answer (score 1):

You could check for it at the beginning of each loop:

```
for (int k=0; k<mat.outerSize(); ++k)
  for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(mat,k); it; ++it)
  {
      if(it.row() < it.col())
          continue;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! I was trying SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(mat,k) + k. But that did not work. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Is there any issue with the first option? it.row() >= it.col() will this make the inner loop breaks when the upper half contains nonzero?

Comment: Why would a non-zero value have anything to do with it? If we wrote ‘&& !it.value()’ then yes, but we didn’t.

Comment: Consider a matrix say [1 2; 2 1] and the element 2 in row 0 column 1. The inner loop will break when it sees this 2 since 0<1. If I understand it correctly, the inner loop only loops through nonzero elements.

Comment: No, this 2 is only accessible as `it.value()`, and in the loops, we're only checking `it.row()` and `it.col()`, which return the indices.

Comment: The corresponding row and col to the 2 is 0 and 1, agree? 0< 1 so the it.row() > it.col() is violated.

Comment: If you want the upper/lower half, flip the condition around.

Comment: I think the correct way to do it is to loop until row() > col() and then start doing something operations. But in your answer, the loop could break before it reaches the lower half.

Comment: Sorry, I only now got that you want to go over the lower triangle of a row major matrix. Use the second version and replace `break` with `continue`.